# Datepicker returning time which I do not want to save

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, google-sheets, datepicker

I was trying a minimal app following this React example: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-and-googlesheets/

**How to reproduce the problem?**
I created the project by following the two/three instructions at the above link. Which is:

```
npx create-react-app react-googlesheets
```

```
npm install semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css
```

Adding the following at `index.js`

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
```

```
npm install axios
```

Then, I used the following at my App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Form, Container, Header } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SemanticDatepicker from 'react-semantic-ui-datepickers'; //https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-semantic-ui-datepickers
import 'react-semantic-ui-datepickers/dist/react-semantic-ui-datepickers.css';
import TimePicker from 'react-time-picker'; //https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-time-picker
// import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker'; //https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-picker
import './App.css';

function App() {
    // const [currentDate,onChange]=useState(new Date());
    const [currentDate, setNewDate] = useState(new Date());
    const onChange = (event, data) => setNewDate(data.value);
    const [getTime,setTime]=useState('10:00');

    const [meter1, setM1] = useState('');
    const [meter2, setM2] = useState('');
    const [meter3, setM3] = useState('');

    console.log(currentDate);
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const objt = { currentDate,getTime,meter1,meter2,meter3 };

        axios
            .post(
                'https://sheet.best/api/sheets/xxx',
                objt
            )
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    };

    return (
        <Container fluid className="container">
            <Header as="h2">Meter Reading Entry</Header>
            <Form className="form">
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>DateTime</label>
                     {/* <DateTimePicker 
                     onChange={currentDate} 
                     value={onChange} 
                     /> */}
                    <SemanticDatepicker 
                    onChange={onChange} 
                    value={currentDate} 
                    format="D/MMM/YY"
                    />
                    <TimePicker 
                    onChange={setTime} 
                    value={getTime}
                    />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Meter1</label>
                    <input
                        placeholder="Enter Meter1 reading"
                        onChange={(e) => setM1(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Meter2</label>
                    <input
                        placeholder="Enter Meter2 reading"
                        onChange={(e) => setM2(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Meter3</label>
                    <input
                        placeholder="Enter Meter3 reading"
                        onChange={(e) => setM3(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Field>

                <Button color="blue" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I have used a Google Sheet and made it REST friendly through http://sheet.best the details are given at the first link above.

What I am doing here is: an entry system for household meters saving with current/custom date and time.

Now, my problem is when I save date they look gibberish like: `2021-05-03T18:00:00.000Z`

I have used formatter but that did not help. What am I doing wrong with the Date picker?

Comment: I guess this probably is related to TimeZone. Thats why the time shown is about 6hours less than inputted. And the time data is enclosed by T and Z. Hope anyone experienced with DateTime functions can help.

Comment: I alternatively used this DateTimePicker too. But it also encloses time with the letters T&Z at my GoogleSheet. I would award the person who has the trick to get rid of TZ from GoogleSheet from the app.

Comment: Date time picker I am trying alternative is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calling `axios.post` - you'r sending `currentDate` as type Date, which uses `Date.toString` method to convert it to string. By default `Date.toString` using full date time format including timezone. You should format the date before sending as you wish to get it on backend. You may do formatting by yourself or use one of libraries like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Here is an example (without any library):

```js
// ...
function myPrettyDateFormat(d) {
  const pureDateStr = d.toString().split('T')[0]
  const timeStr = `${d.getUTCHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}`
  return `${pureDateStr} ${timeStr}`
}

function App() {
    const [currentDate,onChange]=useState(new Date());
    // ....
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const objt = { currentDate: myPrettyDateFormat(currentDate), getTime,meter1,meter2,meter3 };

        axios
            .post(
                'https://sheet.best/api/sheets/xxx',
                objt
            )
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    };
```

Comment: I have used another DateTime picker which has Date and time both selectable. But that also shows time 6 hours minus entered time and also encloses the time between the letters, T&Z. I think I need to set a timezone too.

Comment: I am mainly interested to get rid of that 'TZ' part from the time shown.

Comment: Example: `axios.post('https:/sheet.best/api/sheets/xxx', {...objt, currentDate: myFormatDate(currentDate)}).then...`

Comment: Please show how the myFormatDate would actually contain. A bit novice with JS.

Comment: function myFormatDate(d) { 
  return \`${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth()+1}-${d.getDate()}\`; 
}

Comment: Shame on me I could not use the function. Should I declare it on a const to use inside the handler function? Also if you notice the comments I did under my question, I am willing to award the answer if anyone solves me the 'T&Z' part to not show and also correcting the timezone. My Google Sheets timezone is same as my PC's timezone.

Comment: If you want just to remove the 'T...'  time part from the date. Use: `currentDate.toString().split('T')[0]` :-)

Comment: I am requesting you to edit your answer to respond my queries in details. Like showing exact way of how the functions would look like in my App.js. I would be very happy to award the answer to you if you do so. StackOverflow does not like us to extend discussions over comments a lot.

Comment: Just noticed you have updated the code. I will get back after trying the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Oleg really helped, but I think I should document how I finally solved with his code, so anyone trying the exact packages/libraries dealing with date/time at Google Sheet gets helped.

I'll post the whole App.js for anyone wondering.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Form, Container, Header } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import axios from 'axios';
import TimePicker from 'react-time-picker'; //https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-time-picker
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker'; //https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-picker
import './App.css';

function myPrettyDateFormat(d) {
    const pureDateStr = d.toString().split('GMT')[0];
    return `${pureDateStr}`
  }
function App() {
    const [currentDate,onChange]=useState(new Date());

    const [meter1, setM1] = useState('');
    const [meter2, setM2] = useState('');
    const [meter3, setM3] = useState('');
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const objt = { currentDate: myPrettyDateFormat(currentDate),meter1,meter2,meter3 };

        axios
            .post(
                'https://sheet.best/api/sheets/xxxx',
                objt
            )
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    };

    return (
        <Container fluid className="container">
            <Header as="h2">Meter Reading Entry</Header>
            <Form className="form">
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>DateTime</label><br/>
                     <DateTimePicker 
                     onChange={onChange} 
                     value={currentDate} 
                     />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Meter1</label><br/>
                    <input
                        placeholder="Enter Meter1 reading"
                        onChange={(e) => setM1(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Meter2</label><br/>
                    <input
                        placeholder="Enter Meter2 reading"
                        onChange={(e) => setM2(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Meter3</label><br/>
                    <input
                        placeholder="Enter Meter3 reading"
                        onChange={(e) => setM3(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Field>

                <Button color="blue" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default App;
```

As you might notice, I am currently using the react-datetime picker to get Date and Time in one go/single control. Was getting weird date + time outputs.

I realized part of Oleg's function was adding some unwanted time digits too. So I rewrote this function as:

```js
function myPrettyDateFormat(d) {
    const pureDateStr = d.toString().split('GMT')[0];
    // const timeStr = `${d.getUTCHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}`; alert(timeStr)
    return `${pureDateStr}`
  }
```

Thanks a lot to Oleg again for all the help!

Comment: The whole DateTime string storing to sheets was like: `Thu May 06 2021 13:24:07 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time) 7:24`